# Replacing "invisible" special characters with something legible

Tags: string, vb.net, fonts, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

About twelve years ago, I wrote a small VB.NET application that loads strings from files. These strings may contain one or more of the following characters: à, è, é, ì, ò, ù, ä, ö. The application uses a special custom font (JazzText Extended) that does not have those special characters. Yet, I somehow managed to make the application display words correctly *in that font*, and twelve years later, I have no idea how - thanks for not leaving a line of comment, past me!

The program has the following routine:

```
Private Sub SetWord(ByVal word() As String)

    Dim nword(3) As String
    nword(0) = word(0)
    nword(1) = word(1)
    nword(2) = word(2)


    For i As Integer = 0 To 2
        nword(i) = nword(i).Replace("à", "")
        nword(i) = nword(i).Replace("é", "")
        nword(i) = nword(i).Replace("è", "")
        nword(i) = nword(i).Replace("ì", "ê")
        nword(i) = nword(i).Replace("ò", "")
        nword(i) = nword(i).Replace("ù", "")
        nword(i) = nword(i).Replace("ä", "")
        nword(i) = nword(i).Replace("ö", "")
    Next

    lblItaWord.Text = nword(0).ToUpper
    lblEngWord.Text = nword(1).ToUpper
    lblFinWord.Text = nword(2).ToUpper

End Sub
```

What it does is, it takes an array that contains three words, and for each of those three words, it looks if it contains any of the special characters. If it does, it replaces them with... something, makes the words all caps, and then assigns each of them to one of three labels.

In Visual Studio, the replacement characters look like empty strings. I had to put the cursor in between the quotation marks to realise that it was in fact not an empty string and there was an invisible character there. Here on SO... I'm not sure what you'll see. You might see just a square, or some other weird character. (The ê character is an exception, it seems to display in the same way everywhere.)

If you copypaste any of the invisible/square characters to Google and search for it, you'll get a different representation that uses *two* characters—for example, the first one translates to Â‡. Using this pair in place of the invisible/square character in the `Replace` method does not produce the correct result. FYI, the encoding I use to read the files (the default one used by `IO.StreamReader` if you don't specify any encoding) works fine: if I use a more standard font, all special characters display correctly without using the `SetWord` sub at all.

Now, I have absolutely no idea *how* those characters, whatever they may be, manage to make the app display correctly the words when the font I use does *not* have those characters. I have no idea how I found out about this trick, either. Right now, my problem is that I would like to replace those squares/invisible characters with something intelligible, and I have no idea how. Any ideas?

Comment: Your `Â‡` looks like a UTF-8 two-byte character interpreted as two ASCII or ANSI single-byte characters.  If you want to do some inspection, you could try something like `Char.ConvertToUtf32` to see what the chars are (or you could open the file with a hex editor).